# How to send json data over http

Tags: json, http

I am new to http protocol. When we are sending json message over http to server, How we need to send ?

1. we need to send the data from different port each time

OR

2. we can send data form a single port in each time.

If I want to use existing connection to send data in future then whether it is possible or not ?

Comment: Why on earth would you send data from a different port each time.

Comment: `client is listeing `...interesting...

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think the OP believes that you cannot reuse a socket ever

Comment: @iharob You're supposedly right, but then, I'm even not sure about that. Oh, and did I mention the tag-spamming?

Comment: @sourave Ghosh I want to send a data which contains json body with http header to a server.Let I am using socket FD1 to send the data to server and I got the response.When I want to send data **2nd time** to server which socket I will use ? Is it `FD1` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you would create a TCP socket for each piece of data you want to send — *and this has nothing to do with HTTP* — and particularly not through a different port each time. In fact, once you hace the socket created and you have connected to the server you should in principle always talk to the server through that socket.

Also, the HTTP protocol uses the port 80, and HTTPS uses 443. That number does not change on demand. Of course you can send HTTP requests through any available port you want and some services even run on special ports using HTTP as the communication protocol but normaly HTTP is 80. See the [`/etc/services`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html) file on linux and read about [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html).